# How to compare 2 properties that are in a mongo document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents in mongo and they have properties of  `{number1: <some number>, number2: <some other number>}` I want to do a query where `number1 < number2` without using the `$where` operator (as it is not performant).  This query is part of an aggregate pipeline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to do this in an aggregation pipeline then use [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/):

```js
{ "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
        "if": {
            "$lt": [ "$number1", "$number2" ]
        },
        "then": "$$KEEP",
        "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
}}
```

It allows logical comparison and removal in a single stage. If you have an older MongoDB than 2.6 then you can `$project` the logical result and `$match` to filter these out instead.

```js
{ "$project": {
    "someField": 1,
    "test": { "$lt": [ "$number1", "$number2" ] }
}},
{ "$match": { "test": true } }
```

Comment: This is great, thank you.  Can I do nested if/else, or can I use $or and $and in the if condition?

Comment: @CSharpAtl Depends, if you actually mean "nested" then of course you nest. `$cond` is a "ternary", so typically another `$cond` as the argument to "else". Otherwise it is just logical inclusion with `$and` or `$or`. See the [boolean operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-boolean/). But this was not your question you asked If you have another question then [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). It makes things very unclear when you ask additional questions or something completely different in this context.